# How to map get values by dynamic key from array of object?

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

I want to fetch object values by dynamic key inside `map()` if possible.

```js
const array = [
  { "ts": 1620988054, "KEY1": 14, "KEY2": 23, "KEY3": 58 },
  { "ts": 1620901654, "KEY1": 46, "KEY2": 34, "KEY3": 42 },
  { "ts": 1620898054, "KEY1": 16, "KEY2": 44, "KEY3": 24 }
];
let data = {};
const arrayOfKeys = [ "KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3" ];
const keyObject = { "KEY1": "KEY1", "KEY2": "KEY2", "KEY3": "KEY3" };

for (let index = 0; index < arrayOfKeys.length; index++) {
  const key = Object.keys(keyObject)[index];
  data[key] = array.map(({ KEY1 }) => KEY1);
  data[key] = array.map(({ KEY2 }) => KEY2);
  data[key] = array.map(({ KEY3 }) => KEY3);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [
      {"ts":1620988054, "KEY1":14, "KEY2":23, "KEY3":58},
      {"ts":1620901654, "KEY1":46, "KEY2":34, "KEY3":42},
      {"ts":1620898054, "KEY1":16, "KEY2":44, "KEY3":24}];
    
    const data = array.reduce((acc, cur) => { // loop through array
       const {ts, ...rest} = cur; // for each item, isolate ts from the rest
       Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k, v]) => { // loop through the rest
        if (k in acc) acc[k].push(v) // if we already have an array for the key, push the new value to it
        else acc[k] = [v]; // else create a new array with that key/value pair
       });
       return acc
    }, {});
  
    
    
    console.log(data);
```

Comment: I didn't understand it very well but ty anyway.

Comment: Basically I loop through each item of the array, I then isolate `ts` and put all of the other keys and values in the `rest` variable. I then loop through `rest` and put the values in the array corresponding to the key.

Comment: @DevM I've added comments. This solution is dynamic and allows you not to hard-code an array of keys

Answer (score 0):

If you want an object containing keys that correlate with your array of keys, you can reduce the items in the array by reducing over the array, and within the items, reducing the keys.

```js
const array = [
  { "ts": 1620988054, "KEY1": 14, "KEY2": 23, "KEY3": 58 },
  { "ts": 1620901654, "KEY1": 46, "KEY2": 34, "KEY3": 42 },
  { "ts": 1620898054, "KEY1": 16, "KEY2": 44, "KEY3": 24 }
];
const arrayOfKeys = [ "KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3" ];

const data = array.reduce(
  (accOuter, record) => arrayOfKeys
    .reduce((accInner, key) => ({
      ...accInner,
      [key]: record[key]
        ? [...accInner[key], record[key]]
        : accInner[key]
    }),
  accOuter),
  Object.fromEntries(arrayOfKeys.map(key => [ key, [] ])));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```